# Extend life Bearer Token (Unified REST Api)

Tags: office365

After base64 decoding my bearer token, i notice the lifespan was only 1H, the documentation say the same, 1h.

I would like a lifespan of at least 2-3 month, but in the microsoft api, i don't see such options, its written only

> This request requires a URL-encoded payload of the following format:
>   
>   grant_type=authorization_code 
>    &redirect_uri=uri 
>    &client_id=id 
>    &client_secret=secret_key 
>    &code=code 
>    &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F

Anyone can help me figuring out which other params i should pass in my POST request.

```
token_url = '{0}{1}'.format(self.AUTHORITY, '/common/oauth2/token')
post_data = {
                   'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
                   'code': auth_code,
                   'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
                   'resource': 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
                   'client_id':  self._client_id,
                   'client_secret':  self._client_secret
                }

request = requests.post(token_url, data = post_data)
return request.json()
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to extend the lifetime. However you should also receive a refresh token which you can use to request new tokens without user interaction.

Comment: Thanks Jason, i guess i will have to deal with it, i knew about the refresh_token, but i would have wished a refresh_token valid for 1 or 2 years andan access_token at least 2-3 month, not only 1H.